# Issue of roRegistrySection in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to create a roRegistration section and write a two function GetAuthData and SetAuthData I tried to pass multiple Argument in SetAuthData and Read using GetAuthData.

```
Function GetAuthData() As Dynamic
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
' print "section : " + Authentication
 if sec.Exists("Authentication")
  print "Read URL : " + m.top.GlobleURL
  print " ****************** DATA :" + m.top.GlobleURL
  return sec.Read("Authentication")
 'return sec.Delete("Authentication") ' Here not override concept so compalsary delete first and after again second URL Store pannel.brs and hud.brs both file

 print "***********************GetAuthData************************"
 endif
 return invalid
End Function

'Here the SetAuthData to wrire URL
Function SetAuthData(Serverurl As String,zxorausername As String, zxorapassword As String) As Void
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
 m.top.GlobleURL = Serverurl
 m.top.globalusername = zxorausername       
 m.top.globalpass = zxorapassword
sec.Write("Authentication", m.top.GlobleURL)
sec.Write("Authentication", m.top.globalusername)
sec.write("Authentication", m.top.globalpass)
?"key for the URL" sec.GetKeyList()

    Print "Write URL :" + m.top.GlobleURL
    Print " Write username :" + m.top.globalusername + " Write pass :" + m.top.globalpass

 print "***********************SetAuthData************************"
End Function
```

And I call GetAuth data like below

```
m.top.GlobleURL = GetAuthData()
m.top.globalusername = GetAuthData()
m.top.globalpass = GetAuthData()
```

And I print it all three item but every time print m.top.GlobleURL value. I tried to Store all three value. But store only one value. Does anyone know this issue?

**EDITED POST**

```
Function GetAuthData(key as string) As Dynamic
' reg = CreateObject("roRegistry")
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
' print "section : " + Authentication
 if sec.Exists(key)
        return sec.Read(key)
 end if
    return invalid
 'return sec.Delete("Authentication") ' Here not override concept so compalsary delete first and after again second URL Store pannel.brs and hud.brs both file

 print "***********************GetAuthData************************"
End Function

'Here the SetAuthData to wrire URL
Function SetAuthData(Serverurl As String,zxorausername As String, zxorapassword As String) As Void
' reg = CreateObject("roRegistry")
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
 m.top.GlobleURL = Serverurl
 m.top.globalusername = zxorausername       
 m.top.globalpass = zxorapassword

' if not m.top.GlobleURL = Serverurl 
    sec.Write("url", m.top.GlobleURL)
    sec.Write("username", m.top.globalusername)
    sec.write("password", m.top.globalpass)
sec.Flush()
?"key for the URL" sec.GetKeyList()
    Print "Write URL :" + m.top.GlobleURL
    Print " Write username :" + m.top.globalusername + " Write pass :" + m.top.globalpass
' end if
 print "***********************SetAuthData************************"
' Flush(true)
End Function
```

and print using the

```
m.keyUrl = GetAuthData("url")
m.keyUserName = GetAuthData("username")
m.keyPassword = GetAuthData("password")

?"URL Print : "  m.keyUrl
?"Username print : " m.keyUserName
?"password print : " m.keyPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are writing the '*Authentication*' key inside the '**Authentication**' section. And you are writing to the same key i.e. it is getting overwritten. Thats why you are gettig only one key. Please use write function () as --

```
Function SetAuthData(Serverurl As String,zxorausername As String, zxorapassword As String) As Void
    sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
    m.top.GlobleURL = Serverurl
    m.top.globalusername = zxorausername       
    m.top.globalpass = zxorapassword
    sec.Write("url", m.top.GlobleURL)
    sec.Write("username", m.top.globalusername)
    sec.write("password", m.top.globalpass)
    sec.Flush()         // add this to code
    print"key for the URL" sec.GetKeyList()
End Function
```

Make the get function generic to access multiple keys as--

```
Function GetAuthData( key as String) As Dynamic
sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
    if sec.Exists(key)
        return sec.Read(key)
    endif
    return invalid
End Function
```

Now you can access the keys as--

```
keyUrl = GetAuthData("url")
keyUserName = GetAuthData("username")
keyPassword = GetAuthData("password")
```

hope this will help.

(**Note:-** You can use "**ReadMulti**" method to read multiple keys at a time. But personaly, I will suggest to not using it as it will involve creating and reading AssociativeArrays, and will create unnecessary complications.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here Directly access to key attribute?

Comment: Yes, without specifying the key, how you will access the value. And how the registry will know which key you want to read.

Comment: Sorry I get the invalid in a output

Comment: Make sure you are writing the key values correctly.

Comment: @Nikunj, Sorry there was typo in getauthdata function. I typed keys instead of key in argument. Please correct this in your code. I edited it now.

Comment: ya, thats I Got It But I put All code same as you But Getting an invalid in a console log.

Comment: Wait I Edit my answer pls check now

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya I checked the code with dummy data. Its working fine. Please check that you are passing proper values to "SetAuthData" function. And make sure that you are calling "GetAuthData" only after calling "SetAuthData", otherwise you may get invalid values.

Comment: Thank you and Sorry. It's working Now. It's a mistake on My flow.